# Zenpy; custom fields are not being updated

Tags: python, zendesk, zendesk-api

So within Zendesk I created these custom fields as follows:

[image]

and now I am trying to create a user with all these fields filled with preset values. But when I try to create users, like follows:

```
for row in df.iloc[1:11].fillna(0).iterrows():
    user = User(name = row[1].first_name,
    email = row[1].email,
    lifetime_value = row[1].purchased_total_value,
    first_order = row[1].first_purchased,
    last_order = row[1].last_purchased,
    products_ordered = row[1].purchased_product_count,
    total_orders = row[1].purchased_unique_orders,
    total_returns = row[1].total_returns,
    products_returned = row[1].products_returned,
    pro_account = pd.notna(row[1].proaccount_deal),
    verified=True)
    created_user = zenpy_client.users.create(user)
```

All users are created however only with email and name fields filled up and all the custom fields which I created are empty. Zenpy's `User()` function is not very informative in this regard however it accepts `**kwargs**` and as per json representations in documentation, it should work in theory. Any workaround or my mistakes in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using user_fields?

```
for row in df.iloc[1:11].fillna(0).iterrows():
    uf = {"lifetime_value" : row[1].purchased_total_value,
    "first_order" : row[1].first_purchased,
    "last_order" : row[1].last_purchased,
    "products_ordered" : row[1].purchased_product_count,
    "total_orders" : row[1].purchased_unique_orders,
    "total_returns" : row[1].total_returns,
    "products_returned" : row[1].products_returned,
    "pro_account" : pd.notna(row[1].proaccount_deal),
    "verified":True}
    
    user = User(name = row[1].first_name, email = row[1].email, user_fields=uf)
    created_user = zenpy_client.users.create(user)
```

This should work, but if it doesn't you could try creating the user first and then querying for them, and then seeing all of your custom fields in `user.user_field`.

Doing so would allow you to see all the available custom user fields you can enter in. From there you can update the object and `zenpy_client.users.update(user)` it into the system.